# how to sync files with different names between server and device

Tags: android, contacts, synchronization

I have vcard files on a web server and i'm trying to build a restore app that retrieves those contacts and import them to the phone in case they're not exist or update .
the file name ends with the original contact id (for example: noa_32.vcf).
The problem is that when i try to use restore more than once i get duplicated contacts.
in order to avoid this duplication there is a way of creating another file wich contains information  about each file and its matching name on the phone.

the quastion is: Is there any other way to handle the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be solved in many ways. One approach can be like this:
create a table `"Restored_VCards"` with colums `Vcard_id, contact_name` and android `contact_id`
in sqlite data base. 
before restoring each vCard, query if the vCard id and name  is already existing in the db.
if its not existing  then restore otherwise skip processing this vCard.

Thus you can get rid of redundancy .

Ask me if you face any trouble.

good luck.

Comment: Create a database called RestoredVcardsDB , and create the table in sqlite Database.